# How to pass additional arguments to a Control.Monad.Reader instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm reading the [Book of Monads](https://leanpub.com/book-of-monads) and I got to the `Reader` monad where the motivation for using `Reader` is presented using this example:

```
handle :: Config -> Request -> Response
handle cfg req =
    produceResponse cfg (initializeHeader cfg) (getArguments cfg req)
```

To avoid explicitly passing the `cfg` argument the `Reader` is used as following:

```
handle :: Request -> Reader Config Response
handle req = do header <- initializeHeader
                args <- getArguments req
                produceResponse header args
```

The part that confuses me are the functions which beside the `cfg` take additional parameters. How can I achieve that?

In a pretty naive attempt I tried this:

```
getArguments :: Reader Config (Request -> Arguments)
produceResponse :: Reader Config (Header -> Arguments -> Response)
```

I also searched in a couple of books and in the `Reader` docs.

Comment: Are you asking for the types of `getArguments` and `produceResponse`?

Comment: The types and the corresponding invocation of these two functions inside the do block.

Comment: your `getArguments` should have type `Request -> Reader Config Arguments`, surely? (And similarly for `produceResponse`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That attempt is definitely not naive, though it is not the usual way of doing things.

Since `Reader r a` is really just a function `r -> a` behind the scenes, your definitions of `getArguments` and `produceResponse` are essentially:

```hs
getArguments :: Config -> Request -> Arguments
produceResponse :: Config -> Header -> Arguments -> Response
```

Notice that in this case `Config` is always the first parameter, so things like `getArguments req` will not work - after all, `Request` is the second parameter of `getArguments`, not the first one, so you can't just apply `getArguments` to `req`.

What you need to do is to first apply `getArguments` to `Config`. Since we're actually working with a `Reader Config ...` and not a simple function `Config -> ...`, we do that by binding `getArguments`:

```hs
handle req = do header <- initializeHeader
                argumentGetter <- getArguments
                -- rest omitted
```

Since `getArguments` is a `Reader Config (Request -> Arguments)`, `argumentGetter` will simply be a function `Request -> Arguments`. Using such a function is then trivial:

```hs
handle :: Request -> Reader Config Response
handle req = do header <- initializeHeader
                argumentGetter <- getArguments
                let args = argumentGetter req
                -- rest omitted
```

You could then go on and apply the same treatment to `produceResponse` and things would work.

However, at the start I said that this is not the usual way of doing things. Consider these definitions:

```hs
getArguments :: Request -> Reader Config Arguments
produceResponse :: Header -> Arguments -> Reader Config Response
```

If we unwrap the `Reader`, we'll see that these are actually just:

```hs
getArguments :: Request -> Config -> Arguments
produceResponse :: Header -> Arguments -> Config -> Response
```

That is, `Config` always comes as the last parameter. This is in contract to what we had at the start, where `Config` always came first.

Defining `getArguments` and `produceResponse` like this works nicely in your original example:

- `args <- getArguments req` - `getArguments` applied to `req` produces a `Reader Config Arguments` and binding that to `args` makes `args` an `Arguments`
- `produceResponse header args` - `produceResponse` applied to `header` and `args` produces a `Reader Config Response`, which fits nicely as the last statement in the `do` block

Note that we could do a transformation like this for `Reader` since `Reader` is just a function anyway, but in general for any `Monad m`, there's a quite a bit of difference between `m (x -> y)` and `x -> m y`, with the latter being the most common for "parameterized" monadic operations.

For example, consider `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`. You provide a `FilePath` and it gives you an IO action that produces the contents of the file. If instead it were `IO (FilePath -> String)`, it would be an IO action that produces a function `FilePath -> String` - that is, a pure function that, when given a `FilePath`, produces the contents of a file. However, since it's a pure function it can't have any side effects, so it can't actually *read* the file and thus this would not really work (`getFile` could do crazy stuff like read the whole filesystem first, but let's not get into that).

Comment: Thanks. Eventually I got the same idea while reading: https://dev.to/riccardo_cardin/and-monads-for-almost-all-the-reader-monad-1ife Namely `repo => repo.sell(stock, quantity)`

Answer (score 0):

One option I used in the past is to make a custom record type

```
data Context = Context
   { config :: Config
   , header :: Header
   , args :: Arguments
   }
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
foo :: Int -> Reader Context String
foo x = do
   h <- asks header        -- get the header from the implicit context
   a <- asks args
   doSomething x h a
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question, though? I guess that one could define a `GetArgumentsContext` and then do something like `args <- withReader (\cfg -> GetArgumentsContext { cfg = cfg, header = header }) getArguments`, and while there are definitely cases where such a transformation would have value, I don't think that that's the case here.

Comment: @f4st I can't completely understand what the OP really needs. If they need to pass multiple values around, this is a way to do it, provided all those values are known from the very start. If instead sometimes you want to pass X and Y, other times Y and Z, and so on, then using a large record like this is unfeasible or at least inconvenient.

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants the example code (the second one that actually uses `Reader`) to work as is. That is, they want to pass `Config` around and nothing else.

But yeah, your solution works when there's more stuff to pass around and it's not just a one-off thing.